# VBA - Validate quantity including the field being edited

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

Setup: MS Access + SQL Server 2019.
I have Purchase Orders which have to be Delivered. For example:

| PurchaseOrderDetailID | QtyOrdered |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |

| DeliveryID | DateShipped | DateReceived |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1.2022 | 2.1.2022 |
| 2 | 1.2.2022 | 2.2.2022 |

| DeliveryDetailID | DeliveryID | PurchaseOrderDetailID | QtyDelivered |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 3 |

This means that there are 10 items ordered, 5 items have been delivered in the first Delivery, 3 items in the second one, therefore 8 delivered in total.
Meaning that this Purchase Order is partially delivered at the moment.

I have a Delivery Data Entry Form in MS Access (back end is SQL Server). I want to validate the quantity so that TotalQtyDelivered cannot be more than TotalQtyOrdered.

```
Private Sub txtQuantity_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim QtyOrdered, QtyDelivered, LeftToDeliver As Double
    
    QtyOrdered = DLookup("QtyOrdered", "dbo_v_PurchaseOrderItemStatus", "PurchaseOrderDetailID=" & Me.PurchaseOrderDetailID)
    QtyDelivered = DLookup("QtyDelivered", "dbo_v_PurchaseOrderItemStatus", "PurchaseOrderDetailID=" & Me.PurchaseOrderDetailID)
    
    LeftToDeliver = QtyOrdered - QtyDelivered
    
    If Me.txtQuantity > LeftToDeliver Then
        MsgBox "TOO MUCH"
        Me.Undo
        Cancel = True
    End If
    
End Sub
```

This works fine if I'm entering a new Delivery. But if I am editing an existing delivery, the algorithm accounts also for the previous value in the Qty field.

With the example above:

```
QtyOrdered = 10
QtyDelivered = 8
```

(this is calculated by SQL View)

Let's say that I made a mistake and there were actually 4 items delivered in the second delivery, istead of 3. When I try to change the value, this happens:

```
Me.txtQuantity = 4
LeftToDeliver = 2
```

(because it still accounts for the "3" previously inserted in Me.txtQuantity

Result: Operation failed, too many items. However in reality there should only be 9 items.

Can you please advise how I should do this correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Change your application logic. When you are editing, you need to "save" the original quantity value when retrieved and then adjust your calculation to logically erase the original value in your calculation. When adding, you simply set that value to zero. However, you are open to a race condition here as well as subject to changes made by others to the same purchase. I leave those issues to you to address.

Comment: Change must be committed to table for the DLookup calculation to consider it. You are using BeforeUpdate event for the calc. If you don't want to commit until validation, add code that checks if this is NewRecord and if not check textbox OldValue against its NewVialue. Use the difference in your calc.

Comment: Correction, OldValue and Value properties.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Didn't know about OldValue property. Thanks a lot! Can I mark this as the answer somehow?